# Regex to capture numbers up to 2 digits and coma if followed by another word and number

Tags: python, regex

I need a regular expression that matches and return 2 numbers from a string when conditions are met

1. only numbers with a maximum of 2 digits and not greater than 29 (might include a decimal case - so up to 2 digits plus 1 decimal case)
2. they must have in between either one of the characters `y` or `+` and after the second number the word 'houses'

And then capture both numbers

for the string below:

```
8 y 13 houses, 13 y 8 houses, 13 y 13 houses, 8 y 8 houses, 120 y 8 houses, 8 y 120 houses, 13,5 y 8 houses, 13,5 y 120 houses
```

I would get

```
8 and 13 / 13 and 8 / 13 and 13 / 8,8 / 13,5 and 5
```

I was trying with this

```
\b([0-9][0-9]?)\s[y|\+]\s([0-9]{1,2})\shouses\b
```

but can't manage to get the ',' as well.

Comment: To capture one of a set of characters, you'd want to use `[y+]`, you don't want to match the `|` as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the | was there to match with either "y" or "+"...

Comment: @user2950162 `|` is not needed in a character class.

Comment: @user2950162: you are confusing optional parts of a group (`(?abc|def)`) with a character class (`[abc]`); the former matches either `abc` or `def`, the latter matches *one* character, `a` or `b` or `c`.

Comment: @Totem thanks for the link, very complete

Comment: Do you want to match something like `29,3` as well?

Comment: @Totem: There are errors on that page; it uses `[d|c]og` an example, creating the impression that the `|` has meaning other than match one of `cog`, `dog` or `|og`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You If you want to match the optional decimal value with an optional group:

```
re.compile(r"\b([1-2]?\d(?:,\d)?)\s[y+]\s([1-2]?\d(?:,\d)?)\shouses\b")
```

where `(?:,[0-9])?` will match a comma followed by a digit if present. Note that I limit the digit matching to values between 0 and 29; matching an optional `1` or `2` first, followed by `0-9`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> demo = '8 y 13 houses, 13 y 8 houses, 13 y 13 houses, 8 y 8 houses, 120 y 8 houses, 8 y 120 houses, 13,5 y 8 houses, 13,5 y 120 houses'
>>> pattern = re.compile(r"\b([1-2]?\d(?:,\d)?)\s[y+]\s([1-2]?\d(?:,\d)?)\shouses\b")
>>> pattern.findall(demo)
[('8', '13'), ('13', '8'), ('13', '13'), ('8', '8'), ('13,5', '8')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a try:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re

str = '8 y 13 houses, 13 y 8 houses, 13 y 13 houses, 8 y 8 houses, 120 y 8 houses, 8 y 120 houses, 13,5 y 8 houses, 13,5 y 120 houses'

regex = r'''
\b (
    [012]?     # number may go up to 29, so could have a leading 0, 1, or 2
    [0-9]      # but there must be at least one digit 0-9 here
    (,[0-9])?  # and the digits might be followed by one decimal point
)
\s* [y+] \s*   # must be a 'y' or '+' in between
(
    [012]?     # followed by another 0-29
    [0-9]
    (,[0-9])?  # and an optional decimal point
)
\s* houses \b  # followed by the word "houses"
'''

for match in re.finditer(regex, str, re.VERBOSE):
    print "found: %s and %s" % (match.group(1), match.group(3))
```

Demonstration:

```
$ python pyregex.py 
found: 8 and 13
found: 13 and 8
found: 13 and 13
found: 8 and 8
found: 13,5 and 8
```

When that regex matches a string in your input, the first number will be in `match.group(1)` and the second number will be in `match.group(3)`.

Comment: If you use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` you can make the decimal point group non-capturing, leaving the other groups addressable as groups 1 and 2 instead.

Comment: Yes, your solution is better for that. I have always been averse to the PCRE `(?...)` regex extensions, not always to my benefit.

Comment: *shrug* I use whatever features the current Python implementation has to extract every last ounce.